# How to define the weighted average of two functions?

Tags: functions

Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ be two sets, and let
\begin{gather}
\Delta(B)=\left\{\delta\in[0,1]^B\mid\sum_{b\in B}\delta(b)=1\right\}
\end{gather}
be the set of all lotteries over the set $B$. Further, let $f:A\to\Delta(B)$ and $g:A\to\Delta(B)$ be two functions satisfying $f\neq g$. Then, define the function $h:A\to\Delta(B)$ as follows:
\begin{gather}
h=(2/3)f+(1/3)g
\end{gather}
I have three questions regarding such a construction:

1. Is the function $h$ a legitimate construction?
2. If it is, does it really have domain $A$?
3. If it is, is the function $h$ as previously defined equivalent to defining it as
   \begin{gather}
       (\forall a\in A)[h(a)=(2/3)f(a)+(1/3)g(a)]
   \end{gather}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer. Yes.

(3) is the way you define the sum of functions.

Your notation is correct but much more formal than necessary.
The straightforward way to describe this situation is to say that a convex combination of probability distributions is a probability distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. While I understand your short answer, I don’t really understand your full explanation. First, why will the codomain of $h$ be the set of functions on subsets of B? Second, why if a function has value other than $0$ or $1$ will not be a lottery? As I defined them, lotteries are just probability distributions. Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: You are right. I was confused by your too elaborate formal definition of "lottery". You should just have called them probability distributions. I will edit my answer.